# manual renewal for android inapp subscriptions before expiry date

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

According to the [billing subscriptions documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#manual-renewal), there is a possibility of triggering a manual renewal before the current subscriptions has expired.

For eg. If I invoke the same purchase flow on a particular monthly sub 2 times in a row, the second one will fail with the error 'You have already subscribed to xxx'. I am expecting it to succeed and add an additional month to the expiry date.

Is there a way of manually renewing IAP before the expiry date?

Answer (score 0):

the manual renewal will happen with subscription recovery.